# Vue JS console logging return an Observer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, console

Here how are my datas in the store :

[image]

Here my code :

```
       fetchNotifications() {
            let notifications = {}

            axios.get('/api/unreadNotifications')
                .then(response => {
                    notifications = response.data
                    if(notifications) {
                        this.$store.commit("updateNotifications", notifications)
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log()
                });
        },
        checkDisplayQuestionnaire() {
            console.log(this.$store.state.notifications)
        },
```

If i `console.log(response.data)` in the `.then` of `fetchNotifications()`, datas are like this :
[image]

I tried to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.notifications))` without success.

Anyone have an idea of the problem ? Thanks you.

Comment: How is this failing? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I get just an {__ob__: Observer}
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Object

Comment: `__ob__: Observer` is Vue's reactivity. In other words, it's Vue's handle on that data and it's needed so that every place where you use the data can be updated when you make changes to it. In other words, it's not a bug, it's a feature. Besides, when deep copy-ing it, it's lost. Other than not knowing why it is for, how is this a problem? Define the failure. The only actual props on it are the ones which are not faded. Everything else is "volatile" and can roughly be defined as "the reason why you use Vue" instead of plain JS.